# Stop all threads from entering a region

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm looking for a way to deal with threads (I guess using semaphors) to stop all threads from entering a certain region for a while. When all threads that are currently in the region get out of it (so no thread is in it anymore), I want to do something that affects this region. After that, the region should be enterable by many threads at the same time again.

I don't see how to do it with the Semaphore since in the documentation I can't find any properties which f.e. Let me change its property on how many can enter the region and even get the amount how many are inside at all.

How could I do this?

Comment: We need to see your task/threading implementation to have a chance of helping you. "When all threads that are currently in the region get out of it (so no thread is in it anymore), I want to do something that affects this region" makes no sense, how can you "affect the region" when there's zero threads? I assume you have a "main" thread, and you are launching a bunch of tasks, and you want the main thread to do stuff in that region but only when no tasks are also in that region.

Comment: Sorry, am I unable to speak theoretically on this board? Its a theoretical thing which is way easier to express like i did instead of posting any tangible code.

Comment: Your title is probably why it got put on hold. Reading your text again your question is more clear: "How do you count the number of threads that are currently "in" a region of code? And how do I differentiate one thread from another so I can only let certain, identifiable threads enter a region?". I don't have an answer to that, but I feel like [Synchronization Events and Wait Handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679037.aspx#Anchor_2) could do it. If you want to "stop all threads from entering a region" then put a `while(true){}` above that region and no threads will enter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds bit like you looking for ReaderWriterLockSlim class. Many thread can enter/get read lock, but only one thread can get write lock.